# Regex for input validation enforcement

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to create a regex that will match on a string of strings with the following format: "static.string static.mod static.bin". I basically want to enforce the string.string format. My current implementation only gets the first string static.string. this is my RE `^(\s*)([A-Za-z]+)(\.+)([A-Za-z]+)`. This only matches the first string, so how do I make it iterate and match any string that fits that format in a string of strings?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)', text)`

Comment: That worked, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)', text)
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fOnbIe/1).

The regex matches:

- `(?<!\S)` - a location immediately preceded with a whitespace or start of string
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `\.` -  a dot
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?!\S)` - a location immediately followed with a whitespace or end of string.